# Print column named as 12/12/12 using pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, multiple-columns

Hey I have a CSV file in it a column named as `12/12/12` and I need to print whole column. Using pandas in python, how can I print it?
While I am trying code:

```
pd=df.12/12/12  
print(pd)
```

It shows invalid syntax

Comment: try: `print(df["12/12/12"])`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that way of indexing as the column name contains `/` characters, you should try using:

```
print(df['12/12/12'])
```